# Get all branches in multibranch pipeline and get all active pipeline job which exclude disabled multibranch pipelines and its branches

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm working on the groovy script to get all active multibranch pipelines and disabled multibranch pipeline list

Below is the groovy script and I was able to get this

```
To get the list of multibranch pipelines

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).each {multibranchpipelines->
println("multibranchpipelines Job Names: " + multibranchpipelines.getFullName())
}
```

```
To get the list of disabled multibranch pipelines
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob).each {multibranchpipelines->
if(multibranchpipelines.isDisabled()) {
println("multibranchpipelines Job Names: " + multibranchpipelines.getFullName())
}
}
```

Now I want to get all the jobs list which is in multibranch pipelines active and disabled separately

I have tried multiple scripts, but still not able to get the required, can someone has ideas or groovy scripts that I can use to get this

Also, once we get the list, can I get the count of those active and disabled

And finally, I want to get the list of all jobs which exclude disabled multibranch pipelines and their branches

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand 100% present what you are try to achieve but I'll try to answer.
First, I suggest to look at the [javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-multibranch/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/multibranch/WorkflowMultiBranchProject.html) of each class that you need.
Second,To get the list of all jobs within active multibranch pipelines, you can modify the first script as follows:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).each { multibranchpipelines ->
    println("Active jobs within " + multibranchpipelines.getFullName())
    multibranchpipelines.getItems().each { branch ->
        branch.getAllJobs().each { job ->
            if (job.isBuildable()) {
                println("\t" + job.getFullName())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get the count of active and disabled multibranch pipelines, you can use the following scripts:

```
def activeCount = 0
def disabledCount = 0

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).each { multibranchpipelines ->
    if (multibranchpipelines.isDisabled()) {
        disabledCount++
    } else {
        activeCount++
    }
}

println("Active multibranch pipelines: " + activeCount)
println("Disabled multibranch pipelines: " + disabledCount)
```

To get the list of all jobs excluding disabled multibranch pipelines and their branches, you can modify the first script as follows:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject).findAll { !it.isDisabled() }.each { multibranchpipelines ->
    println("Active jobs within " + multibranchpipelines.getFullName())
    multibranchpipelines.getItems().each { branch ->
        if (branch.isBuildable()) {
            branch.getAllJobs().each { job ->
                if (job.isBuildable()) {
                    println("\t" + job.getFullName())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the last script, we are using the findAll method to filter out disabled multibranch pipelines before processing them.

Also, I didn't test the code I provided